# Update Label that place on different storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

i have Tabbed application and there is one label on each screen. i want to update all UILabel from one place using swift.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you could show the code you tried (you can edit the question), it will make it easier to help you spot the problem.

Comment: Yes ! you can use 'NSUserDefaults' for this. just set value in NSUserDefaults and get that value for every UILabel. here is link that might help you in NSUserDefaults :-> http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/